# Why is Snoop for WPF crashing when we try attaching it to our application?

Tags: c#, wpf, snoop

When I run Snoop on my WPF application, my application crashes and I get an error saying "BindingFailure was detected". The details of the error are:

`The assembly with display name 'Snoop.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Snoop.XmlSerializers, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Has anybody encountered this problem before? I have no clue what's causing it.

Comment: You must have checked all `exceptions` in the `Debug -> Exceptions` dialog in Visual Studio. Uncheck all "thrown" columns

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

You must have checked all exceptions in the `Debug -> Exceptions` dialog in Visual Studio. Uncheck all "thrown" columns

Comment: I figured that out once upon a time...  Then it happened again today...  I was wracking my brain until I came upon this thread.  Thank goodness for SO.

Comment: GOD... I can't tell you *how many times* I have dealt with that, and it turns out its just a simple checkbox?!!  And here I was thinking we were doing something so agregious and undetectable in our code that we were crashing snoop!  BUT... Question... is there any way to leave that checked but ignore the snoop assembly? In our case, since we run global handlers, we have to engage that checkbox to do proper debugging. Granted, usually not when we need snoop, but it still would be nice not to have to constantly be turning it on and off all the time.